# Which can be updated faster, using or not using additional condition in MyISAM?

Tags: mysql, sql, myisam

I'm trying to update multiple records using a single query in MySQL(Engine: MyISAM).

It looks like:

```sql
UPDATE table_name SET delete_flag=true WHERE column_1={value}
```

I'd like to set all `delete_flag` to `true`.
And then, I came up with adding WHERE clause like this:

```sql
UPDATE table_name SET delete_flag=true WHERE column_1={value} AND delete_flag=false
```

*(delete_flag doesn't have any indexes.)*

Though it could depend on the number of records, I wonder which is the faster way.

Could you give me your advice?
If it depends the situations, please tell me them.

Thanks.

Comment: How is this "multiple records" if you are updating based on an `id`?

Comment: How many records are going to be updated , is it millions ? then there is a chance of locking the table for longer period ,, you may get rowlock if other transactions are waiting for it

Comment: Adding where is good if the field is indexed and very selective. But if the number of updates are huge then you can build a logic of batch update , either in the application logic or through a db procedure .. something like loop and get 500 records to update each time

Comment: I'm sorry I was wrong that "id" was id of another table.

Comment: and I updated the queries.

Comment: Why are you using MyISAM?

Comment: There are restrictions that I can’t change it due to my company circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, `id` is unique in the table, so MySQL is going to find the one row that needs to be updated based on that condition.

MySQL then checks if the value changes before doing an update.  So, the MySQL engine does not do extra work (logging for example) when the record does not change.

Any difference in performance is negligible, and would be rather hard to quantify.

Comment: >MySQL then checks if the value changes before doing an update. So, the MySQL engine does not do extra work (logging for example) when the record does not change.
This is very helpful for me! Thanks. In short, it mean MySQL does never execute useless processes, right?

Comment: @Akumachan . . . I wouldn't say "never" -- because there might be subtle changes that you don't care about and "never" is very strong.  However, MySQL does check before performing the update to be sure that the data has changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `INDEX(delete_flag, id)`, then your second option will run faster because it will look at fewer rows.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I'll ask my team to be allowed to add an index if we need!